# How to modify the agent in an openai gym environment?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I want to modify the agents structure (for example the length of the legs) in the `bipedal_walker` environment.

Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to download and modify the OpenAI `gym` source code, and then use your locally modified version of `gym` in place of the pip package you installed.

For example, if you want to modify the length of the legs in the `bipedal_walker` environment, you'd probably want to play around with the `LEG_H` variable on [this line of code](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/box2d/bipedal_walker.py#L55).

Comment: Thank you :) .. that worked if I want to have the agent's structure fixed. I tried to add a method to modify the agent, but every time I call it, it cannot be identified as a member of the object env :(

Comment: The idea I want to implement require changing the agent's structure rapidly while learning. I 'm not sure how to apply this modification.